# R shiny: How to copy data derived from plotly_selection events into a data frame/table and update each time by pressing an actionButton?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm putting together a shiny app to play around with some athlete GPS data. Essentially, I'm looking to structure my script so that **each time** the user selects an area of interest on the plotly plot and the *"Add"* `actionButton` is clicked, the table below will add the calculated `Start_time`, `Time_at_peak`, `Max_velocity`, `Time_to_peak`, and `Distance_to_peak` values.

The issue can be seen in the GIF below: - Once the area of interest is selected and the *"Add"* button clicked, the first values seem correct. However, when the user selects a second area of interest to add to the table, it overwrites the initial entry and will keep overwriting each time a new selection is made. This is seemingly because because the code is inside the `observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected")`, which, confusingly, it needs to be in order to calculate the variables of interest.

I'm currently a little stumped and can't seem to find any relevant information. As such, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a we transfer link to some test data that can be uploaded to the app: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5a7c5da5a7647bdbe133eb3fdac79c6b20211119052848/afe3e5

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinyjs)

x_df <- data.frame(Start_time = character(1), Time_at_peak = character(1), Max_velocity = integer(1),
                   Time_to_peak = integer(1), Distance_to_peak = integer(1))

x_df$Start_time <- as.character("0:00:00.0")
x_df$Time_at_peak <- as.character("0:00:00.0")
x_df$Max_velocity <- as.integer(0)
x_df$Time_to_peak <- as.integer(0)
x_df$Distance_to_peak <- as.integer(0)


runApp(shinyApp(
  ui=(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Event to Table"),
    
    mainPanel( 
      fileInput(
      inputId = "filedata",
      label = "Upload data file (.csv)", 
      accept = c(".csv")),
      
      plotlyOutput('myPlot'),br(),br(),br(),br(),
              DTOutput("testing"), br(), br(),
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("starttime", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("endtime", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("maxvelocity", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("timediff", width = 3),
                valueBoxOutput("distance", width = 3)
              ),
              useShinyjs(),
              fluidRow(
                div(style = "text-align:center", actionButton("Add", "Add Data to Table"), 
                    downloadButton("export", "Export Table as .CSV"))), br(),
              DTOutput(outputId = "table")))
      
    ),
 
  server = (function(input, output, session) {
    
    data<-reactive({
      req(input$filedata)
      read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, header = TRUE)%>% 
        rename(Velocity = 'Speed..m.s.',
               Player = 'Player.Display.Name',
               Latitude = 'Lat',
               Longtitude = 'Lon',
               AccelImpulse = 'Instantaneous.Acceleration.Impulse',
               HeartRate = 'Heart.Rate..bpm.')
      
    })
    observe({
      thedata<-data()
      updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data))
    })
    
    output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
      
      plot_ly(data = data(), x = ~Time, y = ~Velocity, height = 450,
              marker =list(color = 'rgb(132,179,202)', size = 0.1),
              line = list(color = 'rgb(132,179,202)', size = 0.1, width = 0.9),
              type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines') %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select",
               showlegend = F,
               title = list(text = 'Velocity Trace', font = list(size = 20)),
               xaxis = list(title = list(text = "", standoff = 0), nticks = 10),
               yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Velocity (m/s)"), nticks  = 5, gridcolor = "#46505a"),
               font = list(color = 'black'),
               margin = list(t = 70))
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected"), {
      
      event.data <- event_data("plotly_selected")
      
      if (max(event.data$y) < 1.5) {  
        maxvel <- (max(event.data$y))
        maxpos <- match(maxvel, event.data$y)
      }
      else {
        filter1 <- filter (event.data, event.data$y > 1.5)
        maxvel <- (max(filter1$y))
        maxpos <- match(maxvel, event.data$y)
      }
      
      zero_val <- function(x) x == 0 
      zero_index <- event.data$y[1:maxpos] %>% detect_index(zero_val, .dir = "backward")
      
      if (zero_index==0) {starttime <- event.data$x[1]}
      else {starttime <- event.data$x[zero_index]}
      
      endvel <- which.max(event.data$y)
      endtime <- event.data$x[endvel]
      timediff <- paste(today(), endtime) %>% as_datetime() - paste(today(), starttime) %>% as_datetime()
      
      sprint <- as_tibble(event.data$y[zero_index:endvel])
      ms <- as_tibble(rep(0.1, count(sprint)))
      time_vel <- cbind(ms, sprint)
      
      distance <- sum(time_vel[1]*time_vel[2])
      
      sprintselect <- as_tibble(cbind(Start_time = starttime, 
                                      Time_at_peak = endtime,
                                      Max_velocity = round(maxvel, 2),
                                      Time_to_peak = round(timediff, 1), 
                                      Distance_to_peak = round(distance, 1)))
      
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$df <- x_df
      addData <- observe({
        
        if(input$Add > 0) {
          newLine <- isolate(data.frame(Start_time = sprintselect$Start_time, Time_at_peak = sprintselect$Time_at_peak,
                                        Max_velocity = sprintselect$Max_velocity, 
                                        Time_to_peak = sprintselect$Time_to_peak,
                                        Distance_to_peak = sprintselect$Distance_to_peak,
                                        stringsAsFactors= FALSE))
          
          values$df <- isolate(rbind(values$df, newLine))}
      })
      
      output$testing <- renderDataTable({values$df})    
    
    })
    
  })

  ))
```

[image: Event to table example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out and thought I'd post an answer rather than delete the question - just in case someone out there is looking to do a similar thing and they are unsure how to do it.

Firstly, I removed the pre-populated table `x_df` from the beginning - it was no longer required.

Although I thought the code needed to sit inside the `observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected")` to function correctly, it did not - thankfully, because that was at the root of the issue. Instead, I used `observeEvent(input$Add, {` (which is the correct code to use as opposed to `if(input$Add > 0)`) to anchor the event to the click of the Add button.

The `values <- reactiveValues()` was placed outside the `observeEvent()` and an IF statement was used to either add the data to the `values$df` data frame on it's own if it was the first selection, or bind it to the existing saved data.

Here's the new code and a GIF demonstrating.

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinyjs)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui=(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Event to Table"),
    
    mainPanel( 
      fileInput(
      inputId = "filedata",
      label = "Upload data file (.csv)", 
      accept = c(".csv")),
      
      plotlyOutput('myPlot'),br(),br(),br(),br(),
              DTOutput("testing"), br(), br(),
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("starttime", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("endtime", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("maxvelocity", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("timediff", width = 3),
                valueBoxOutput("distance", width = 3)
              ),
              useShinyjs(),
              fluidRow(
                div(style = "text-align:center", actionButton("Add", "Add Data to Table"), 
                    downloadButton("export", "Export Table as .CSV"))), br(),
              DTOutput(outputId = "table")))
      
    ),
 
  server = (function(input, output, session) {
    
  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
    
    data<-reactive({
      req(input$filedata)
      read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, header = TRUE)%>% 
        rename(Velocity = 'Speed..m.s.',
               Player = 'Player.Display.Name',
               Latitude = 'Lat',
               Longtitude = 'Lon',
               AccelImpulse = 'Instantaneous.Acceleration.Impulse',
               HeartRate = 'Heart.Rate..bpm.')
      
    })
    observe({
      thedata<-data()
      updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data))
    })
    
    output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
      
      plot_ly(data = data(), x = ~Time, y = ~Velocity, height = 450,
              marker =list(color = 'rgb(132,179,202)', size = 0.1),
              line = list(color = 'rgb(132,179,202)', size = 0.1, width = 0.9),
              type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines') %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select",
               showlegend = F,
               title = list(text = 'Velocity Trace', font = list(size = 20)),
               xaxis = list(title = list(text = "", standoff = 0), nticks = 10),
               yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Velocity (m/s)"), nticks  = 5, gridcolor = "#46505a"),
               font = list(color = 'black'),
               margin = list(t = 70))
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Add, {
      event.data <- event_data("plotly_selected")
      
      if (max(event.data$y) < 1.5) {  
        maxvel <- (max(event.data$y))
        maxpos <- match(maxvel, event.data$y)
      }
      else {
        filter1 <- filter (event.data, event.data$y > 1.5)
        maxvel <- (max(filter1$y))
        maxpos <- match(maxvel, event.data$y)
      }
      
      zero_val <- function(x) x == 0 
      zero_index <- event.data$y[1:maxpos] %>% detect_index(zero_val, .dir = "backward")
      
      if (zero_index==0) {starttime <- event.data$x[1]}
      else {starttime <- event.data$x[zero_index]}
      
      endvel <- which.max(event.data$y)
      endtime <- event.data$x[endvel]
      timediff <- paste(today(), endtime) %>% as_datetime() - paste(today(), starttime) %>% as_datetime()
      
      sprint <- as_tibble(event.data$y[zero_index:endvel])
      ms <- as_tibble(rep(0.1, count(sprint)))
      time_vel <- cbind(ms, sprint)
      
      distance <- sum(time_vel[1]*time_vel[2])
      
      sprintselect <- as_tibble(cbind(Start_time = starttime, 
                                      Time_at_peak = endtime,
                                      Max_velocity = round(maxvel, 2),
                                      Time_to_peak = round(timediff, 1), 
                                      Distance_to_peak = round(distance, 1)))
      
          newLine <- isolate(data.frame(Start_time = sprintselect$Start_time, Time_at_peak = sprintselect$Time_at_peak,
                                        Max_velocity = sprintselect$Max_velocity, 
                                        Time_to_peak = sprintselect$Time_to_peak,
                                        Distance_to_peak = sprintselect$Distance_to_peak,
                                        stringsAsFactors= FALSE))
          
          if (is.null(values$df)){
            values$df <- newLine}
          else {
          values$df <- isolate(rbind(values$df, newLine))}
        output$testing <- renderDataTable({values$df})
    
    })
    
  })

  ))
```

[image: Solution]